# There is no compilation error but when running the code clicking the comment button, it is not leading to the activity I want

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, adapter

I did the code below, used the adapter to show the list, and a button to add a comment to list item, it shows the logcat "ViewPostIme pointer 0 and ViewPostIme pointer 1", upon clicking the comment button.

Upon compilation it doesn't show any error, I tried to use many references via google but nothing works out.

My basic idea is to call the comment button with an associated list item to perform the comment activity.

Adapter class

```
public class PostsAdapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<PostsModel, PostsAdapter.PostsHolder> {
    private OnItemClickListener listener;
    private View.OnClickListener buttonListener;


    private String id;

    private static final String TAG = "DocSnippets";


    public PostsAdapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<PostsModel> options) {
        super(options);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PostsHolder holder, int position, @NonNull PostsModel model) {
        //retrieve the fields here
        holder.textViewDescription.setText(model.getPostContent());
        holder.textViewPriority.setText(String.valueOf(model.getSpinnerC()));
        holder.textViewPriority.setText(String.valueOf(model.getTimestamp()));
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public PostsHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.post_list_layout,
                parent, false);
        return new PostsHolder(v);
    }

    public void deleteItem(int position) {
        getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position).getReference().delete();
    }

    public void setOnClickListener(OnClickListener postKey) {
    }


    class PostsHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        //first declare here the elements to be displayed in the cardview.
        TextView textViewTitle;
        TextView textViewDescription;
        TextView textViewPriority;

        Button commentsbutton;

        public PostsHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textViewTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_etPostTitle);
            textViewDescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_description);
            textViewPriority = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_time);
             commentsbutton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.commenting_button);


            commentsbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION && buttonListener != null) {
                        buttonListener.onClick(itemView);

                    }

                }
            });
        }
    }

    public interface OnClickListener
    {
        void OnClickListener(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, int position);

    }
    public void setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener onClickListener) {
        this.buttonListener = onClickListener;
    }


    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, int position);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }
}
```

Fragment Class

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {


    RelativeLayout mParent;
    //FloatingActionButton addButton;

    private static final String TAG = "DocSnippets";

    private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    private CollectionReference PostsRef = db.collection("posts");

    private PostsAdapter adapter;
    private FirestoreRecyclerOptions options;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private String mUserId, id;

    private Button commentsbutton;

    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //just change the fragment_dashboard
        //with the fragment you want to inflate
        //like if the class is HomeFragment it should have R.layout.home_fragment
        //if it is DashboardFragment it should have R.layout.fragment_dashboard
       View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        final FragmentActivity c = getActivity();
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(c);

        Query query = PostsRef.orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING);
        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<PostsModel> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<PostsModel>()
                .setQuery(query, PostsModel.class)
                .build();
        adapter = new PostsAdapter(options);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
             recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(c));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            commentsbutton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.commenting_button);

         mParent =view.findViewById(R.id.relative_home);
       mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mUserId = mAuth.getUid();



        adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new PostsAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, int position) {
                PostsModel note = documentSnapshot.toObject(PostsModel.class);
                 id = documentSnapshot.getId();
                String path = documentSnapshot.getReference().getPath();
                Log.d(TAG, "String post Id is: " + id);


            }
        });

        adapter.setOnClickListener(new PostsAdapter.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void OnClickListener(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, int position) {

                PostsModel note = documentSnapshot.toObject(PostsModel.class);
                id = documentSnapshot.getId();
                String path = documentSnapshot.getReference().getPath();
                Log.d(TAG, "String post Id is: " + id);
                Intent toCommentActivity = new Intent(getContext(), CommentActivity.class);

                 toCommentActivity.putExtra("PostKey", id);

                getContext().startActivity(toCommentActivity);


            }
        });







        return view;



    }


    private String getTime(long timestamp){
        long ts = timestamp*1000;
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
        String time = sdf.format(new Date(ts));
        return time;

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }

}
```

Comment: Where you call OnClickListener(DocumentSnapshot,position ) in your adapter?

Comment: no , I am calling it in HomeFragment class

Comment: I found in your fragment class you implemented it but where you pass the (DocumentSnapshot,position) ??

Comment: I used it to get the document id of the post   >>>>>id = documentSnapshot.getId(); that is the id of the list item to be retrieved from firestore database, so that the comment can be added to the particular post list item

Comment: I am talking about interface. You implemented it but never hit the method. So how your implemented method will be call?? If call then getContext().startActivity(toCommentActivity); will be called.. And change getContext() from your new Intent(getContext(), CommentActivity.class); and add getActivity()